# Is it risky to allow every IP on SQL Server?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I made an application which connects to SQL Server and write/read data and it works only on my IP address. I could can allow every IP address, is this risky or is there no way someone can see my database log in data?

Comment: What do you mean by "every IP"? As in that anyone with access to the internet would be able to connect to the server? If so, then **yes** that's a *terrible* idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 100% dangerous.

According to tags, I guess you are connecting to a SQL Server via an Android app. If that's the case, there are TONS of ways to find the credentials. For example, one can intercept the requests, decompile your code, or...

Even if you hadn't an Android app published, your server will be under heavy brute-force attacks on the Internet.

At least, you need a webserver to handle authentication, on your web server and then the web server connects to your database in a very limited and safe way.

Comment: yes, that's what i did, im bad with php, how i can make that server on easiest way?

Comment: @GoranTerzic I'm afraid I can't provide any easy solution. Using Firebase cloud databases is one solution in a limited way. But the ultimate solution is to develop a whole backend Api. It's not limited for Php